# How can I use JavaScript private fields in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm using the [proposed private field syntax](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields#private-fields) in my JavaScript but VS Code says this is a syntax error:

[image: Errors for provide fields]

The specific error is: `Invalid character. ts(1127)`

How can I make VS Code understand private fields?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Cause

VS Code uses the [TypeScript project](https://github.com/microsoft/typescript) to power both its JavaScript and TypeScript IntelliSense. The TypeScript project only added support for private fields [in TypeScript 3.8](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30829). However the current release of VS Code (1.41) only includes the latest stable TypeScript 3.7 release.

If you see syntax errors for private fields, you are likely using a version of TypeScript in VS Code that does not yet understand private fields.

## Workaround

VS Code 1.43 (to be released early March 2020) will include TypeScript 3.8. Until then, you can upgrade your workspace to use a newer typescript version by either:

- Installing [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next)
- Following [these instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling#_using-newer-typescript-versions)

Keep in mind that other VS Code extensions—such as linters—may also need to be updated with support for private fields