# Why does Intellisense suggest this["__#12345@#methodName"] for a 'private' JS method?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Example code:

```js
class Test {
  load() {
    // Typing here
  }

  #doLoadAction() {
    ...
  }
}
```

When I type `doLoadAction()` (or part of that) in the `load()` function above, where it says `// Typing here`, I would expect Intellisense (code completion / suggestion) to suggest either `this.#doLoadAction()`, or `Test.#doLoadAction()` when the method is static.

Instead, I get something like `this["__#12345@#doLoadAction"]`. The set of numbers seems to be random. With a non-private function, code suggestion and completion works perfectly fine.

I'm guessing that this code would work just fine, but for readability purposes, I don't want it. What is causing this, and can it be prevented?

---

<s>**Addition:**
I forgot to test private fields (variables) before, so I just did. For those I don't get a suggestion at all, regardless of where I try to access them.</s>

**Addition 2:**
Oddly, while continuing my programming, I noticed that private fields now **do** get suggested properly, and come in like `this.#fieldName`, so it seems like that section is either a bit buggy, or my previous test was incorrect.

Comment: I assume the code intellisense picks up some compiled version of this code. Presumably, it internally transpiles it to an ES level that doesn't have private fields.

Comment: Related: [How can I use JavaScript private fields in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59640931/4642212).

Comment: @VLAZ That's an option, but I myself don't compile the code (AFAIK that is), I just use it straight for a webpage. Would it compile something on its own?

Comment: @SebastianSimon Not really, that question is about a syntax error related to private fields, I'm not getting an error, I'm getting weird suggestions. Also, the accepted answer mentions that this should work just fine with TypeScript > 3.8. The current TS version in VSCode is 4.2.3, hence why the syntax error is no longer there.

Comment: @Timmiej93 probably. The autocomplete you get suggests it does, because this seems like compiled code. It might be some sort of internal representation of the code you've typed.

Comment: how do you think intellisence works, to analyze the code you have to compile it, by introducing this random stuff it is unlikely a programmer has thought of naming his function like this and thus will not make a call from outside the class to that name